# Search C Drive for all existences of file type

Tags: search

I am new to VB and am creating a small project. I need to be able to search the `C:\` drive for any instance of my search string.

Example.  `.jpg` is a file type to search for. I want to be able to find all `.jp"` on the computer. Not the main file system just the users files and folders.

My program already creates the folder where I want the results copied to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> FindFilesInDirectory(string dirPath, string searchName)
{
    return Directory.Exists(dirPath)
               ? Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .ToList()
                          .ConvertAll(x => new FileInfo(x))
                          .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()))
               : null;
}
```